# How to use reserved keyword 'year' in dynamodb query

Tags: java, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I tried to fetch the records on behalf of year(reserved keyword) from dynamodb.

But could not get success.

```
DynamoDBScanExpression queryExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
queryExpression.withFilterExpression("year = :year).withExpressionAttributeValues(valueMap);
result = dynamoDBTemplate.scan(ABC.class, queryExpression);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
      DynamoDBScanExpression queryExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();

      Map<String, AttributeValue> valueMap = new HashMap<>();

     valueMap.put(":year", new AttributeValue().withS(2016));

    queryExpression.withFilterExpression("#y = :year).

   .withExpressionAttributeValues(valueMap);

   Map<String, String> expression = new HashMap<>();

            expression.put("#y", "year");

     queryExpression.withExpressionAttributeNames(expression);
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, String> rwnm = new HashMap();
rwnm.put("#a", "action");

QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec();
querySpec.withFilterExpression("#a > :action");
querySpec.withNameMap(rwnm);
querySpec.withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":action", "LightsOn"));
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? It doesn't even contain the specific keyword